# What does it mean in python AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have 4 python files. From PHP i run the first python file that call the others, but i got this error:

```
AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1
```

What does it mean?

[Here](http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/28/accessinit-hash-collision-3-both-1-and-1/#the-solution), talks about the same module called in different way, it is possible?

```
# Import this carefully
try:
    import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    pil_available = True


from PIL import Image, ...
```

I checked my "import module" i don't have found a different importation

Those are my imported modules:

```
import os
import glob
import scipy
import numpy as np
import pymorph as pm
#import pylab as plb
import os
import math
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import mahotas as mh
from skimage import morphology
```

Answer (score 0):

The [link provided by Airswoop1](http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/28/accessinit-hash-collision-3-both-1-and-1/) provides one approach, but there's actually an even easier solution given in the comments. I simply added this at the top of my script:

```
import sys
import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image
```

The author of the comment suggests putting it in your project's `settings.py`, but I don't have one, and it turned out not to be necessary.

Comment: Credit to [ChaunceyNahsco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6515791) for this comment: `...  you have to be careful about where you place the import statement. If it is after matplotlib import for example, it crashed for me. But works after import sys.`