# Django + apache + multiple sites + pillow cause "AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1" or "UnsupportedOperation: fileno"

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have a django project, where sites are deployed dynamically from admin. It includes following settings for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName branch1.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/
WSGIDaemonProcess project_multisite user=project group=project processes=5 threads=5
WSGIProcessGroup project_multisite
```

Then *.htaccess* file (which is generated by app) located  at /home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/ chooses which *apache.wsgi* file will be used:

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^static/ - [L]

{% for site in sites %}
RewriteRule ^site_{{site.id}}/apache.wsgi - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} {{site.domain}}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_{{site.id}}/apache.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
{% endfor %}
```

Problem is that then randomly (around 50 % of requests) apache crashes with error:

```
AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1
[Thu Feb 12 11:48:02 2015] [error] [client 89.176.103.182] Premature end of script headers: apache.wsgi,
```

I found the [discussion about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349503/what-does-it-mean-in-python-accessinit-hash-collision-3-for-both-1-and-1) and adding following code to all *apache.wsgi* files almost solved my issue:

```
import sys
import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image
```

Problem is, that since that time some functionality of PIL stopped to work and I started to get this error when working with JPEG images:

```
 Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error] Internal Server Error: /admin/main/gallery/1/upload-photos/
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/site_1/../../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/site_1/../../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 105, in _wrapped_view
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/site_1/../../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 52, in _wrapped_view_func
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/site_1/../../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 206, in inner
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/site_1/../../../../src/main/admin/branch.py", line 166, in upload_photos_form
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     photo.thumb_admin.save(afile.name, afile)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/multisite/site_1/../../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_resized/forms.py", line 43, in save
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     thumb.save(new_content, format=img.format, quality=self.field.quality, **img.info)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     save_handler(self, fp, filename)
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 476, in _save
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error]     fh = fp.fileno()
[Thu Feb 12 20:33:11 2015] [error] UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Im using:

- Django 1.7.4
- Pillow 2.2.2 (but tested this issue also with 2.7.0)

My question is how to solve this issue so I wouldn't get any of this two errors. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:
Behavior of application depends on position of PIL import overriding in apache.wsgi:
First variant (below) results in *UnsupportedOperation: fileno*  desribed above (probably because debian standard version of PIL is imported):

```
import os
import sys
import site

import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'site_{{site.id}}'

www_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../../../../')
sys.path = [
    os.path.join(www_dir, 'deploy/settings/'),
    os.path.join(www_dir, 'src'),
    os.path.join(www_dir, 'deploy/env/lib/python%s/site-packages' % sys.version[:3])
] + sys.path

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Second variant (below) results still in *AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1*. So it in fact doesn't help at all:

```
import os
import sys
import site

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'site_{{site.id}}'

www_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../../../../')
sys.path = [
    os.path.join(www_dir, 'deploy/settings/'),
    os.path.join(www_dir, 'src'),
    os.path.join(www_dir, 'deploy/env/lib/python%s/site-packages' % sys.version[:3])
] + sys.path

import PIL.Image
sys.modules['Image'] = PIL.Image

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```