# AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run the code below;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Image
```

This is the response am getting.

> AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1

I will be very grateful for your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `from PIL import Image` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349503/what-does-it-mean-in-python-accessinit-hash-collision-3-for-both-1-and-1

Comment: That's it buddy Thanks